# Running a program in Vim with output in the same window

Tags: c, vim, compilation

I wrote a makefile to compile my code in vim with

```
:make
```

Now I don't want to do

```
:! ./program_name
```

because it takes too long. What is fast way to run and compile my code and see it in the same window in vim? Is it possible to have the output of my program in copen? or is that only for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default rule in Makefile to compile and run together.

```
default: app run

app: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

run:
    ./app
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've issued `! ./program_name`, you can quickly repeat it with `:!!`. You can even combine this with `:make|!!`.